# Unit lib-init-rw.mount not loaded?

Tags: apt, 15.04, mysql, systemd

I'm trying to install mysql but got this error:

```
    # apt-get install mysql-server
    E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.

    # dpkg --configure -a
    Setting up systemd (219-7ubuntu6) ...
    Failed to stop lib-init-rw.mount: Unit lib-init-rw.mount not loaded.
```

Any advice?

ps: ubuntu 15.04

**UPD1: message after cancelling process**

```
^Cdpkg: error processing package systemd (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script was interrupted
Errors were encountered while processing:
 systemd
```

Comment: Read the message - "you must manually run 'dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem." , so open a terminal and run `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and post any further errors

Comment: @bodhi.zazen You need to read my message again. I already run it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it.

```
apt-get update
apt-get clean
apt-get autoclean
apt-get autoremove
apt-get check
apt-get -m update
apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: @Dooley_labs Im using it for server only. No gui.

Comment: alright, I'll remove my comment then.